# Openbox VNC on startup

Tags: startup, vnc, xvfb

I'm trying to get a openbox based VNC to run on start up, I have added the following to rc.local

```
  Xvfb :1 -extension GLX -screen 0 800x600x16& 
  DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/openbox-session&
  x11vnc -many -create  -display :1&
```

However the second line never appears to run, If I ssh into the machine after startup VNC is running but not an openbox session and I have to manually enter the second command (at which point everything works as intended.

Is there anyway to make this completely automated?

(I am aware there is no password and that is intended)

Comment: Are you certain it never runs? Perhaps the display isn't ready yet when that command is started and openbox fails. I don't know much about openbox, but you could try saving its output somewhere: `DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/openbox-session &> /tmp/openbox.log &`

Comment: You're right, the display wasn't ready yet.
Put a few second delay in and now it's works perfectly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are backgrounding `Xvfb`, `openbox-session` is started almost immediately after `Xfvb` is started. So the display isn't ready yet when `openbox-session` starts. Something like:

```
sleep5; DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/openbox-session &
```

Should give `Xvfb` enough time to start the display.